# ~ごろ or ~ぐらい for non-clock points in time?

Tags: grammar, particles, time

This is probably a ridiculously simple question, but somehow I've been unable to pin down the answer myself.  To say "about / approximately" for non-clock points in time, do you use ごろ or ぐらい?  [This question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42328/can-%e3%81%90%e3%82%89%e3%81%84-be-used-to-replace-%e3%81%94%e3%82%8d) explains clock time but not non-clock time. For example, which of the below is correct:

> １１月ごろ(に)、アメリカに帰国します。

> １１月ぐらい(に)、アメリカに帰国します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> １１月ごろに、アメリカに帰国します。
> １１月ぐらいに、アメリカに帰国します。

Both sound good to me. ぐらいに sounds more informal than ごろに.

> １１月ごろ、アメリカに帰国します。

sounds good, too. But...

> １１月ぐらい、アメリカに帰国します。

sounds a bit off. ぐらい needs to be used with に in this structure.

---

Similarly...

> 去年の秋ごろ買いました。
> 去年の秋ごろに買いました。
> 去年の秋ぐらいに買いました。

> 2000年ごろ、日本に来ました。
> 2000年ごろに、日本に来ました。
> 2000年ぐらいに、日本に来ました。

> 9月1日ごろ、入荷する予定です。
> 9月1日ごろに、入荷する予定です。
> 9月1日ぐらいに、入荷する予定です。

sound okay to me. ぐらいに sounds more informal.

Answer (score 1):

~ごろ is used for approximate time. You would use it when saying something such as  " at about noon, I ate lunch." Just change out the time of day with the month or whatever and you will be fine.

~ぐらい (くらい) is used to expression a duration of something. Use this when saying "I slept for about 8 hours."